# react component first props is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help. My problem is that the first props is null in my component. It is the state in a parent component.

I have this code for the state:

```js
this.state = {
  popupTrigger: false,
  feeds: [
    {
      Title: "",
      id: "",
      IsLiked: "",
    },
  ],
  likes: "",
  likebuton: false,
}
```

The code in the child component contains:

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      likes: [],
      comments: [],
      likebutton: false,
      popupTrigger: false,
      commentinput: "",
      triggercomment: false,
      countcomment: 0,
      countlike: 0,
      changecomment: "",
      likeId: "",
      likestatus: this.props.likestatus,
  }
```

```js
{this.state.feeds.map(item => {
    <Post
      countlike={async () => {
        var config = {
          method: "get",
          url:xxxxxxxxxx `,xxxx
          headers: {xxxxxxx
            Authorization: `Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx
            )}`,
          },
        }
        await instance(config)
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({ likes: response.data })
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }}
    
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      likestatus={item.IsLiked}
    >
    </Post>
```

This component is passing. The status of the first  is null. The others are true.

Comment: show the code where you are passing the props to child component.

Comment: Please add proper code to understand.